# Unable to find taglib[min] for URI

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with a self made Tag. I receive following error

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to find taglib [mine] for
>   URI: [randomThings]
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:294)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:81)...

Here is also a picture of the error

[image]

But I think everything in the jsp-File is correct. Here is the code

...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="randomThings"%> 
Advisor Page<br> 
<mine:advice user="${userName}" />
```

...

Here is the tld file which I deployed in WEB-INF

```
 <tlib-version>1.2</tlib-version> 

 <short-name>RandomTags</short-name> 

 <uri>randomThings</uri> 

 <tag>          
<description>random advice</description> 
    <name>advice</name>     
<tag-class>com.example.model.AdvisorTagHandler</tag-class> 
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
<attribute> 
 <name>user</name>          
  required>true</required>
  <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>   
</attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

Comment: if you need any other informations, let me know it

Comment: Aside from everything else, please include the image as code, because as image it isn't searchable and it too many clicks away from being saw.

Comment: you are right. I have put the important error stack in the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change uri of

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="randomThings"%>
```

to

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mine" uri="WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>
```

(`custom.tld` is the name of tld file)